# Excel Workbook.XmlMaps

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code which is falling over on a line with `Workbook.XMLMaps`. What exactly is this? There are no direct references to opening a ".xml" file within the VBA.

Is there some sort of repository of xml files within the sheet? If so, how can I find out what this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a combination of pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> (for the VBA help file) and searching Google, preferrably in that order:

> "XmlMaps Object - Represents the collection of XmlMap objects that have been added to a workbook"

And then about the `XMLMap` object:

> "XmlMap Object - Use the Import method [of the XmlMap object] to import XML data from an XML data file into cells mapped to the specified XmlMap. The ImportXml method imports XML data for a String variable."

And finally a few examples from the internet can be found in the following post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnrdurant/archive/2010/01/29/excel-2010-xml-maps.aspx